# " EOL while scanning string literal"

Tags: python

how can i count the number of spaces in a long text without getting the" EOL while scanning string literal"? and also uusing the function 'count', the text is: "'I'm sure I'm not Ada,' she said, 'for her hair goes in such long  ringlets, and mine doesn't go in ringlets at all;"

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Is it possible that whatever you're using for a text editor broke that string into two lines?

Answer (score 4):

This error, like any [`SyntaxError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError), only comes from the parser.

Unless you're calling `eval`, `exec`, or (in Python 2.x) `input`, that means the problem string is *in your code*, not in the input. For example, maybe it's something like this:

```
spaces = s.count(" ')
```

In that case, you've got a string that starts with the double-quote, and goes until the next double-quote. Since there is no next double-quote, that's a syntax error.

Or, as Mark Ransom points out, if the string itself is a literal in your code, maybe your text editor split it into two lines:

```
s = "'I'm sure I'm not Ada,' she said, 'for her hair goes in such long ringlets, and 
mine doesn't go in ringlets at all;"
s.count(" ")
```

In this case, again, you've got a string that starts with the first double-quote, and there is no next double-quote on the line, so it's the same syntax error. (Although in this case, you're not even getting to the line with the `count` that you're complaining about. This is why exceptions have tracebacks: to tell you, or the people who are trying to help you, where the problem actually happened, so you don't have to guess.)

---

If you *are* using `eval` or a related function, you're asking Python to treat a string as if it were code, and that string has a similar problem.

The obvious solution there is to not call `eval`.

If you're calling `input` in Python 2.x, that's the same thing as `eval(raw_input(…))`, so just change to `raw_input`.

Comment: "this error only comes from the parser". +1 I didn't know that.

Comment: @RickTeachey: Well, the OP didn't show the traceback or mention that the error type was [`SyntaxError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError), which means you'd only really know that if you recognized the "EOL while scanning" description string…

Answer (score -1):

You are probably not applying [the `str.count()` method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) correctly (i.e., you have an invalid string).

```
s = "'I'm sure I'm not Ada,' she said, 'for her hair goes in such long ringlets, and mine doesn't go in ringlets at all;"
#If you get the same SyntaxError: EOL at this point, there is something
#wrong with the string you are inputting.
s.count(' ') #Result: 22
```

Comment: First, the question already says he's using `count`. Second, `string.count` is not a method but a function, and it's a deprecated function that does the same thing as the `str.count` method, so I'm not sure why you think switching to that would help.

Comment: Yes, `str.count` is a method—as I said—while `string.count` is not. Whether you're telling the user to use the same method he's already using, or telling him to switch to a function that does the same thing instead, I don't see how that's going to help.

Comment: There is no way you can use the method incorrectly that would raise that exception. So he's obviously doing something _else_ wrong. If you can't guess what that something else is, you can comment, vote to close the question, or downvote the question, but writing an answer that can't possibly address the problem is not helpful.

Comment: That's not using `count` incorrectly, that's typing a literal incorrectly and not even getting to use `count`. That is, in fact, exactly what my answer explains. But if that's the OP's problem, how would your answer show him that he has a problem, explain what the problem is, or show him how to solve it? It doesn't offer anything useful.